# how to convert List<Map<String, String>> to Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have list of map `List<Map<String,String>>` and want to convert into `Map<String, List String>>`

Below is the sample code

```java
List<Map<String,String>> recordListMap = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String,String> recordMap_1 = new HashMap<>();
recordMap_1.put("inputA", "ValueA_1");
recordMap_1.put("inputB", "ValueB_1");
recordListMap.add(recordMap_1);

Map<String,String> recordMap_2 = new HashMap<>();
recordMap_2.put("inputA", "ValueA_2");
recordMap_2.put("inputB", "ValueB_2");
recordListMap.add(recordMap_2);
```

I tried the below approach and with this I am not getting the required result:

```java
Map<String, List<String>> myMaps = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<String, String> recordMap : recordListMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> map : recordMap.entrySet()) {
        myMaps.put(map.getKey(), List.of(map.getValue()));
    }
}
OutPut: {inputB=[ValueB_2], inputA=[ValueA_2]}
```

Expected Result:

```
{inputB=[ValueB_1, ValueB_2], inputA=[ValueA_1, ValueA_2]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Map#compute section

[Map#compute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

[Map#computeIfPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

[Map#computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

Assuming you don't want to use [Multimap](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), something like that should do the trick.

```
    List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, List<String>> goal = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map<String, String> map : list) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            goal.compute(entry.getKey(), (k,v)->{
                List<String> l = v == null ? new ArrayList<>() : v;
                l.add(entry.getValue());
                return l;
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try it like this.

- `computeIfAbsent` will add the list as a value for the key if the key is absent.
- the `new or existing` list is returned so that an object can now be added to that list.

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMaps = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<String, String> map : recordListMap) {
    for (Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
        myMaps.computeIfAbsent(e.getKey(), v -> new ArrayList<>())
                .add(e.getValue());
    }
}
myMaps.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Another alternative is to use streams.

- stream the list of maps.
- then stream the entrySet of each map, flattening it to a single stream of entries.
- and then group by the key and put the values in a list.

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMaps2 = recordListMap.stream()
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, Collectors
                .mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

both will contain

```
inputB=[ValueB_1, ValueB_2]
inputA=[ValueA_1, ValueA_2]
```

Check out [Map.computeIfAbsent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75965408/how-to-convert-listmapstring-string-to-mapstring-liststring/75965482#75965482)